# Показывать документацию в библиотеке

Tags: android, android-gradle

Как возможно собрать библиотеку так, чтобы в проекте где я использую эту библиотеку, при переходе на тот или иной метод в библиотеке, у меня была видна документация написанная к нему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался данной [статьей](https://medium.com/@hamen/android-library-aar-and-javadoc-6859898cad28).
Для меня станным оказалось то что нет ещё поддержки .aar документирования в Android, ну да ладно.

**Рецепт прост:**

Аннотируете методы к которым хотите видеть аннотации

Пишем task который будет выбирать классы для документирования:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'

    include("**/SomeClass.java")
}
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

После этого пересобираете Вашу библиотеку и вуаля, всё должно работать как часики.